# Ternary operator for multiple conditions in Julia

Tags: julia, conditional-operator

I have Julia code as shown

```
if cxp1_v1 < cxp1_v2 
    d_min = cxp1_v1 
    d_max = cxp1_v2 
else 
    d_min = cxp1_v2
    d_max = cxp1_v1 
end
```

or

```
if cxp1_v1 < cxp1_v2 d_min, d_max = cxp1_v1, cxp1_v2 else d_min,  d_max  = cxp1_v2, cxp1_v1 end
```

Is there a way to accomplish this same in the ternary operator? I tried something like as shown

```
cxp1_v1 < cxp1_v2 ? d_min, d_max = cxp1_v1, cxp1_v2:d_min,  d_max  = cxp1_v2, cxp1_v1
```

but I get

```
syntax: colon expected in "?" expression

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[422]:11
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1196
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cxp1_v1 < cxp1_v2 ? (d_min, d_max) = (cxp1_v1, cxp1_v2) : (d_min, d_max) = (cxp1_v2, cxp1_v1)
```

but I would probably write it as:

```
d_min, d_max = cxp1_v1 < cxp1_v2 ? (cxp1_v1, cxp1_v2) : (cxp1_v2, cxp1_v1)
```

since it seems a bit easier to read, or even:

```
d_min, d_max = minmax(cxp1_v1, cxp1_v2)
```